# Deciding the database

Tags: android, html, mysql, google-app-engine

I need to create an android app and website for the same.
So which database/framework I need to use to build the database so that the app and web's data could be in sync.

Should I use a simple MySQL database and write different webservices to sync data between the app and web OR some framework/tool is available for that.

I am not sure but did the Google App Engine is used for the same purpose.

Any kind of suggestion will be helpful to me.
Thanks!

Comment: deppends on the problem... but anyway, here´s one that will sync automatically http://couchdb.apache.org/

Comment: does google app engine serves the same purpose ??

Comment: appengine is supposed to be a framework for developing whatever the web application... It may serve, it may not, depending on the problem

Answer (score 2):

Deciding on a database type depends highly on what kind of data you want to represent. Your choice is not limited to MySQL as there are various other types of databases available e.g. NoSQL like graph databases but here again it depends how you want to model your data. In your case, you should set up the database server in the cloud and then execute queries against it from within your app and website, thus both will work on the same data.

Comment: mine data will be mostly textual data only.Can you tell me any cloud services which are available?

Comment: Windows Azure is one option, however it's not free (you can sign up for a 30 day trial)

Comment: does google app engine is used for same ??

Comment: app engine is more of an infrastructure that lets you build and deploy applications that scale easily. You can use  Google Cloud SQL along with App engine to store relational MySQL database

Comment: thanks a lot!!..just one more query will CouchDB works same as Google Cloud SQl ?

Comment: No, CouchDB is a type of a database that is document-oriented NoSQL, Google Cloud SQL is relational type